# An exception occurred during a WebClient request. in windows phone

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone, webclient

Here I am put my code which is "An exception occurred during a WebClient request" i put breakpoint and check .it will so this error .for developing i  am using visual studio 2012 ultimate with windows phone sdk8.0 and if request is done successful than my response is in json string .that will show in messagebox .now it show me "System.Net.Webexception:An exception occurred during a WebClient request."

```
public match()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(profile1_loaded);

}
void profile1_loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WebClient wc2 = new WebClient();

    var URI = new Uri("http://192.168.1.17/eyematch/rest1-7-2/api/match");

    wc2.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    wc2.UploadStringCompleted += 
              new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc2_UploadStringCompleted);

    wc2.UploadStringAsync(
              URI, "GET", "action=getMatchNotificationData&sKey=" + 
              GlobalVariables.skey + "&uKey=" + GlobalVariables.ukey);
}
private void wc2_UploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs er)
{
    try
    {
        MessageBox.Show(er.Result);
    }
    catch (Exception eu)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(eu.ToString());
    }
}
```

thank you in advance....

Comment: Have you tried it with a POST?

Comment: yes ,but it will give me a message "Invalid request " but when i check my request and and parameter which i pass in it  is correct than what is the problem . this message is display when authentication of user is failed .this functionality coded in database.

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing this in the emulator or on a physical device? Chances are the address is inaccessible given your network configuration (especially since it is a local network IP).

Comment: I am Testing with emulator .And there is no issue of ip address.

Answer (score 0):

A helpful hint to other people running into this error message: the exception has a .InnerException, so if you change the code above to also output "eu.InnerException", you can get more info.